# RewriteCond doesnt work well

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I using Joomla Joomla! 3.4.4 and also XMAP Component 2.3.3
Now i want to Rewrite url when url was :

> /index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1

Rewrite

> /sitemap.xml

This is my code that i wrote in htacces file,i dont know why doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule .* /index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1 [L]
```

Comment: What do you mean `but not work`? What exactly happened?

Comment: The code didn't work, nothing happened when i used /sitemap.xml